# Delete records older than 24 hours or 1 day based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to write mysql query to delete records older than 24 hours.

The SELECT sql statement which i used is below

```
SELECT * FROM Request WHERE 
timeStamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Table contains lot of records older than 1 day but the result of this sql query is empty. Also it doesn't show any error message.

Timestamp field structure is

```
Name: timeSatamp
Type: timestamp 
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Can somebody help me to find out the mistake in this statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Working examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449017/7186739

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` so this will do what you want

```
SELECT * FROM `ts` WHERE timeStamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM `ts` WHERE timeStamp <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Simply Elegant As Always :)

Comment: You can also just do `<= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATEDIFF instead of the comparing from two date.

```
SELECT * FROM Request WHERE DATEDIFF(timestamp, NOW())>=1;
```

DATEDIFF returns a number of days between two date/timestamp.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449017/7186739

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be like this:

```
SELECT * from Request where FROM_UNIXTIME(timeStamp) <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field timestamp contains 10 digits (like "1566836368") the right answer is

```
SELECT * from Request where FROM_UNIXTIME(timeStamp) <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

like previously suggested by @akshaypjoshi

Answer (score 0):

Delete 24 Hours older records using Mysql

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `dateCreate` < (Now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```